# How do I enable debug on dompdf library?

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using dompdf library to output some reports. I got a file outputing but I am having some strange behavior. How do I enable debug reporting in [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)?

```
  $dompdf = new Dompdf();

  // something like this
  $dompdf->enableDebug();

  $dompdf->loadHtml($template);
  $dompdf->setBasePath(realpath('./'));
  $dompdf->render();
  $dompdf->stream('note');
```

Comment: What type of debug reporting are you looking for?

Comment: Any debug info would be helpful. Mostly layout i think.

Comment: There are two types of debug: visual in the rendered PDF and textual. I guess it would help to know what type of strange behavior you're trying to debug.

Answer (score 6):

Set up the globals like [BrianS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264628/brians) says:

```
global $_dompdf_warnings;
$_dompdf_warnings = array();
global $_dompdf_show_warnings;
$_dompdf_show_warnings = true;
```

Then, instead of streaming the pdf to the browser, dump the warnings array:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
var_dump($_dompdf_warnings);
die();
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several debug options: debugPng, debugKeepTemp, debugCss, debugLayout, debugLayoutLines, debugLayoutBlocks, debugLayoutInline, debugLayoutPaddingBox. They can be passed to constructor like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dompdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf(array(
    'debugLayout' => true,
));
$html = '<b>BOLD</b>';

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf", array("Attachment"=>0));
```

Comment: I tried this but got no debug results. Where does the info print to?

Comment: It adds lines inside PDF for layout elements' borders.

Answer (score 2):

If you want some text debugging try setting the following global variables prior to using Dompdf:

```
global $_dompdf_warnings = array();
global $_dompdf_show_warnings = true;
```