# dompdf image does not show up

Tags: php, dompdf

We are using `dompdf` to generate pdf. We need to add images but we are getting issues adding images..

```
$image = $folder . "something.jpg"; //C:\xampp\htdocs\project/folder/folder/something.jpg
```

We test if the image is accessible:

```
if ( file_exists( $image ) ) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "NOT";
}
```

And the image exist.

We added `enable_remote` to true in

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf( [ 'enable_remote' => true ] );
$dompdf->loadHtml( $html );
```

And still does now. We are getting "X" instead of image. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Error:

> Permission denied on
> C:\xampp\htdocs\project/folder/folder/something.jpg. The file could
> not be found under the paths specified by Options::chroot.
> C:\xampp\htdocs\project/folder/folder/something.jpg

Comment: _"We added enable_remote to true"_ - that's kinda pointless, since you are not dealing with a URL, but a file system path.

Comment: I'd try and make the path use only forward slashes first of all. PHP is usually forgiving about this, but perhaps the library is handling this somehow different.

Comment: _"And the image exist."_ - have you also checked whether it is _readable_?

Comment: @CBroe I tried forward slash and seems not working. And the image should be readable. We are able to open it.

Comment: I meant readable by your PHP script, regarding file permissions. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php

Comment: Also, have you checked if the PHP error log has anything to say?

Comment: Have you tried the options listed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779665/how-do-i-enable-debug-on-dompdf-library?

Comment: @CBroe `is_readable` returns okay.

Comment: @NicoHaase, I tried the debugging option and getting an error. Updated my question.

Comment: Have you tried anything to resolve the given error? Why not set the chroot option to include the directory where your images are stored?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the error message, you have to make sure Dompdf is allowed to read that file by specifying a containing path for the chroot option. You can do that when instantiating Dompdf:

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf( [ 'chroot' => '/xampp/htdocs/project' ] );
```